# Errors create when loading matlab files into python

Tags: python, matlab, file, file-conversion

I am having some trouble loading a `.mat` file into Python. It is a structured array with many main and subheadings etc. and I have two errors when using two different modules to import the files;

```py
res = scipy.io.loadmat('myfile.mat')
```

gives the following:

> return self._matrix_reader.array_from_header(header, process)
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 675, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 723, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 978, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_struct
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 673, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_mi_matrix
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 723, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 978, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_struct
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 673, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_mi_matrix
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 721, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 894, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_cells
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 673, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_mi_matrix
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 721, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 894, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_cells
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 673, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_mi_matrix
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 717, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
>
> File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 879, in
>   scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_char
>
> TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array

When using the `mat4py` module I simply get

> ParseError: Unexpected field name length: 48

Any ideas of a way around such a problem

Comment: Is it large data saved with -v7.3 flag? if so you cannot import it with scipy

Comment: I'm not sure if it has a 7.3 flag but it is a structure array with lots of large data

Comment: PS, is there an alternative module that I can use to import this into python

Comment: There is no simple solution. You can save the data split to smaller pieces, save it large but not in a structure, or call a Matlab engine from python.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, the only problem is I don't want to use Matlab engine because I want to be able to send this to someone who does not have the licence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is saved with the `-v7.3` flag you can use the `h5py` library. 
Edited to show how to walk through a matfile with structs, cells, arrays etc.

```
import h5py
from numpy import ndarray

def explore_v73_matfile(file_name=None, fptr=None, path=None):
    if file_name is not None:
        # open the file
        fptr = h5py.File(file_name)
        explore_v73_matfile(None, fptr, ["/"])
        return
    # walk the file tree. not super efficient if very nested, BUT
    # it is very difficult to address if there is a mix of char and
    # int subscripts (nested cells/structs etc)
    o = fptr[path[0]]
    for p in path[1:]:
        o = o[p]
    if isinstance(o, (h5py._hl.group.Group, h5py._hl.files.File)):
        for k in o.keys():
            if (k == "#refs#"):
                # nothing we need is stored under this key
                continue
            else:
                explore_v73_matfile(None, fptr, path + [k])
    elif isinstance(o, h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset):
        if (o.dtype == "|O"):
            # should work for 1D, 2D, ... ND
            for cell in range(o.shape[0]):
                # MATLAB cell array
                explore_v73_matfile(None, fptr, path + [cell])
        else:
            # probably numeric, maybe char (check dtype)
            # this is where you'd find your numeric data arrays 
            print("/".join(map(str,path[1:])))
            print(o[:])
    elif isinstance(o, ndarray):
        # we're walking through a cell or struct array
        for cell in range(len(o)):
            explore_v73_matfile(None, fptr, path + [cell])
    elif isinstance(o, h5py.h5r.Reference):
        # sometimes structs get linked elsewhere if you stuff them in cells

        # print here because the full address gets replaced by [o]
        print("/".join(map(str,path[1:])))
        explore_v73_matfile(None, fptr, [o])
    else:
        raise TypeError("Undefined Behavior. Check MAT File")
```

Comment: This seems to work really well, I have resaved the original file with the flag and now loaded it into python. I am quite new to h5py and so I was wondering how to convert the <HDF5 object reference> from the structure array into the data that I need. Thanks again for this suggestion, it was really helpful

Comment: @Questioner I’m away from my machine for the evening but I’ll edit my answer tomorrow morning with some data/file/object access examples.

Comment: That really is appreciated, thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: Hi there, I think I have solved the issue with getting a np.array from the object.

Comment: Hi Peter, based on my some my research, I tackled it a slightly (prob less optimised) way:

Comment: Hi all, I just had one further question regarding the use of h5py. For a second file as I simply used  the following code to get it into python, myfile = h5py.File('myfile.mat')
    ref1 = myfile['h']
    ref2 = ref1['M']
    ref3 = ref2['Ctemp']
    unin = ref3[...]
    sh1 = unin.shape  However, the names of the headers are in alphabetical order which is not suitable. I have tried to globally track order ie h5py.get_config().track_order=True before importing the .MAT file however this does not solve the problem. Is this a common issue with h5py and is there a way around it?