# "Can only read from Matlab level 5 MAT-files"

Tags: python, matlab, file, file-conversion

I'm trying to load a file from Matlab into my python using `mat4py`.
I had the following error

```
ParseError: Unexpected field name length: 43
```

when using

```
import h5py
from numpy import ndarray
data_py = loadmat("data.mat")
```

I followed  the advise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200907/errors-create-when-loading-matlab-files-into-python)

So,

```
explore_v73_matfile(file_name="data.mat", fptr=None, path=r"C:/Users/...mypath/data_folder")
data_100E = loadmat("data.mat")
```

However, now I have a new error:

```
ParseError: Can only read from Matlab level 5 MAT-files
```

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to share `data.mat`. Does anyone have a clue how to solve this with the little info I can provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MAT-File Format documentation (PDF)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf) indicate that the last binary structure of a MAT-File is the "Level 5 MAT-files".

> This document describes the internal format of MATLAB Level 4 and
> Level 5 MAT-files. Level 4 MATfiles are compatible with versions of
> MATLAB up to Version 4. Level 5 MAT-files are compatible with MATLAB
> Versions 5 and up.

But the [`loadmat.py`](https://github.com/nephics/mat4py/blob/master/mat4py/loadmat.py) function indicate in the comment of the line 425-429 (as of march 2021):

> ```
> # Check mat file format is version 5
> # For 5 format we need to read an integer in the header.
> # Bytes 124 through 128 contain a version integer and an
> # endian test string
> ```

And `loadmat.py` output an error if your MAT-Files is not compatible.

> ```
>  if maj_val != 1:
>         raise ParseError('Can only read from Matlab level 5 MAT-files')
> ```

So probably that your MAT-Files has been created a long time ago, or with an old matlab version and cannot be read anymore with mat4py.

You should try to read your MAT-File with matlab and save them again.